# Fractions without slash on road signs

Tags: punctuation, orthography

According to the UK Department for Transport *[Traffic Signs Manual](http://tsrgd.co.uk/pdf/tsm/tsm-chapter-07.pdf)*, distances in fractions of miles are written without the dividing line or slash on traffic signs:

[image]

What is the linguistic (i.e. history of language, orthography, etc.) background for this represenation? And can fractions be written without slash elsewhere?

Comment: Road signs with fractional (vs decimal) distances are rare in the US, so I can't say that this practice is "normal" for signs, but it's certainly not uncommon to see fractional values written without the slash in other contexts.

Comment: @Hot Licks Please provide any examples where fractional values are written without the slash. Road signs in the US vary widely regionally, so some communities use decimals, others use fractions. I would agree the former are more common, but not enough to declare the latter "rare." However, they would never appear without the fraction line or slash, in my observation.

Comment: The use of fractions without intersecting line is almost certainly to avoid 'visual clutter' being presented to the motorist. The mind takes a finite time to process symbols, thus road signs are specifically designed to be the simplest of representations in order to offer the least mental distraction possible. It is not a linguistic matter, merely one of economical graphic representation.

Comment: @steviesteele - The "examples" I would dig up would be from newspaper ads and the like.  And never use "never" when referring to either English or government activities.

Comment: @HotLicks all the road signs I know of _only_ use fractions "Exit 1/4 mile". The only decimal I can imagine is something like "Max Wt 10.5 tons"

Comment: @Hot Licks I did not use "never" in reference to English or government activities, it was meant to modify "in my observation." Meaning, "never in my observation" (besides the example provided on the UK road signs) have I seen fractions represented thus. I would still very much like to see another example, picture, graphic, etc., of the "bar-less" fraction.

Comment: Notice that certainly the four and arguably the two echo the slash bar, and only 1/4, 1/2, 3/4 (and perhaps 1/3 and 2/3) will be used. 518/519 would not be as legible without a bar.

Answer (score 5):

**Legibility** is the reason the slash is omitted, according to several sources I found ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_(typeface)), [The Changing (Type)Faces of Britain's Road Signs](http://www.academia.edu/11142836/The_Changing_Type_Faces_of_Britains_Road_Signs), [Taken for granted: the Transport font](https://lewminesce.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/), [Sign Languages (Transport and Ministry typefaces, UK)](https://thebeautyoftransport.com/2014/12/03/sign-languages-transport-and-ministry-typefaces-uk/)). I have never seen fractions written like this anywhere else so I think there is no "linguistic reason".

To quote Wikipedia:

> The Ministry of Transport appointed an Advisory Committee on Traffic Signs for Motorways under the chairmanship of Sir Colin Anderson in 1957 and Jock Kinneir and his assistant Margaret Calvert were appointed as graphic designers to it. All aspects of signing were investigated and tested, initially on the Preston bypass (1958, now part of the M6 motorway), before their introduction on the (London–Yorkshire) M1 motorway a year later. The committee looked at examples from other European countries as well as the USA but Kinneir and Calvert found them somewhat harsh and unsatisfactory. Instead, they developed a more rounded typeface with distinctive tails to 'a', 't', and 'l', and bar-less fractions, all of which helped legibility.

Answer (score 0):

Without the benefit of exhaustive research, other than broad life experience, I believe this is an *innovation* without obvious precedent. It should be noted though that the numbers in the fractions are in a smaller (font) size compared to the whole numbers, and it is only by immediately seeing those in contrast to the size of the font name of the place or the whole number itself that communicates that the number is a fractional representation. I am not aware of this innovation done elsewhere. It would certainly never appear in (formal) book formatting in this manner, (that I have ever encountered), least of all in a text discussing mathematical terms, as it could easily lead to confusion with exponents, chemistry notation using a subscripted number, etc.
Apparently whatever body is responsible for determining the utility and coherence of sign notation in the UK believes that this style of representation is inherently perspicacious, to borrow a phrase from another context. In the USA, on road signs where fractional amounts are used, the fractional slash/line will appear in the fraction. I have not seen any sign example in the US where the line is omitted in the way shown above.